Problem running blazor.web.js in a sub url like /panel/
I'm kinda new to blazor, the default counter.razor works fine but when I copy it to a page like the following it desn't.
@page "/panel/counter2"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
    
}

As you see the problem is I've added /panel to the start of the route. The page is loaded but the button doesn't work. Chrome's console shows me this :

GET http://127.0.0.1:5039/panel/_framework/blazor.web.js
net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

So I tried adding the following to my App.razor:
<base href="/" >

So now the blazor problem is gone. But if I add a bootstrap to my page like following it doesn't work properly:
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Which it's working in the default Counter.razor.
Another thing I've tried is to replace _framework/blazor.web.js with /_framework/blazor.web.js in the App.razor. And remove the extra base tag. In this case Bootstrap woks fine and blazor.web.js is loaded but it has another errors like this one:

GET http://127.0.0.1:5039/panel/_blazor/initializers 404 (Not Found)
It

And It's because of this code inside blazor:
 const t = await fetch("_blazor/initializers", {
                    method: "GET",
                    credentials: "include",
                    cache: "no-cache"
                })

If the fetched url had a / in the beginning there wasn't a problem but it uses this relative urls without a slash at the beginning.
BS: For the bootstrap problem there is no js error shown in the console. But  some classes not working like table-bordered . So I think the problem is with css.

Server/WASM/Auto?  Global or Per Page/Component interactivity?

The question is unclear. You don't add any of those settings to pages, you add them to the root app. Blazor is an SPA (Single Page Application), just like React, Vue or Angular. There are no "other" pages that need to load scripts. The app itself changes what gets displayed, and "pages" are actually components rendered inside the app

@PanagiotisKanavos error RZ9988: The "@page" directive must specify a route template. The route template must be enclosed in quotes and begin with the '/' character.

On top of that, <base href="/" > is already in index.html for Blazor WASM and App.razor in Blazor Server 8. You don't have to add it yourself. How did you create this project? Have you tried creating a new project with just dotnet new blazor and adding pages with different routes?

I can't reproduce this. All that's needed to create a Counter page running at /panel/counter is to copy Counter.razor into a new page and change the root to @page "/panel/counter"

@PanagiotisKanavos yes that's what i exactly did and there was no  there

What else did you do? To get this error you must have done something else as well. Perhaps used the wrong path in a menu, /panel/counter instead of /panel/counter2?. I repeat, I can't reproduce what this question claims.

The only way to get a 404 is to try and change the page route, not menu route, at runtime. Hot Reload will handle the menu change but not the page route change

OK , after trying a lot of crazy things , Just removing the "@rendermode InteractiveServer" let the bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css work ! But I think now I have another problems!
